# Issue with new database for an application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem when I run my android application: it still remembers the old DB even if I changed the DB in assets/databases.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you are referring to? Do you mean sqlite database? If so uninstall you application and run (install) again.

Comment: yes I changed DB with sqlite lite , when I run application it still remember old one , even I uninstall it , is there any option on android studio to fix this issue , I do clean and rerun problem not solved

Comment: Old DB - Database structure or records? Post your code.

Comment: Hi I found the problem on file string.xml when I change it application is crashed .